# How to uninstall Bitcoin Core and remove data

Tags: uninstall, bitcoin

I recently installed Bitcoin Core on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.  It's taking up too much disk space.  How do I completely uninstall the software and remove data to free up my hard drive space?

Comment: Did you install debs from a PPA or maybe compile from source ? Could you provide the output of : dpkg -l | grep bitcoin  ?

Answer (score 6):

#### Remove `bitcoin`:

1. `sudo apt-get remove bitcoind`

Alternatively, you could just disable `bitcoind` from starting at startup:

1. `sudo systemctl disable bitcoind`

#### Remove extra files:

**If you remove your .bitcoin directory, you are removing your wallets/addresses and access to any BTC in those wallets, as well as the blockchain history.**

When you run `bitcoind`, it typically creates a `.bitcoin` directory in the home directory of the running user.  Depending on your setup, this could be a user named bitcoin, or be your user.

1. `rm -rf /path/to/.bitcoind/`

If you're not sure where this path is, you could run the following commands to help find it:

1. `sudo updatedb`
2. `sudo locate .bitcoind`

More specifically, the blocks take up a lot of space and are found in `.bitcoind/blocks/`.

Answer (score 1):

In my version of Ubuntu (18.1) the files are located in `.bitcoin` and not in `.bitcoind` so use these commands:

1. `rm -rf /path/to/.bitcoin/`
2. `sudo locate .bitcoin`